# Why is getItemInHand being crossed out (see image below)

Tags: java, eclipse, bukkit

I am new to creating minecraft plugins, however not new to programming, I am following a tutorial very thoroughly, the video has good ratings so it is trusted, when watching the video the guy has no problems what so ever [(Youtube video on developing minecraft plugins)](https://youtu.be/sdv67ktkG_o?t=6m4s) , so I did some research into solutions but always the line through the code.

Eclipse gives me the option for: @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") which allows the code to be used still but I would rather have no need of that usage.

Basically my question is why is there the need of the line going through the code and how do I find a solution to get rid of it.

**Main class:**

```
package com.jc1;

import org.bukkit.Material;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;

import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

import org.bukkit.permissions.Permission;

import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginManager;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Core extends JavaPlugin
{
     public Permission pPermission = new Permission("playerAbilities.allowed");

@Override
public void onEnable()
{
    new BlockListener(this);
    PluginManager pm = getServer().getPluginManager();
    pm.addPermission(pPermission);
}
@Override
public void onDisable()
{

}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args)
{
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("giveitems") && sender instanceof Player)
    {
        Player p = (Player) sender;

        if(p.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed"))
        {
            p.setItemInHand(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BOOTS));

        }
        return true;

    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

**Secondary class:**

```
package com.jc1;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;

import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockPlaceEvent;

public class BlockListener implements Listener
{
    public BlockListener(Core plugin) 
    {
        plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, plugin);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onBlockPlace(BlockPlaceEvent e)
    {
       Player p = e.getPlayer();

       if(!p.hasPermission("playerAbilities.allowed"))
       {
           e.setCancelled(true);

       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The method is *deprecated*, meaning that it is not recommended to be used  anymore and is most likely replaced with another method.

Methods that are *deprecated* may still work as intended.

---

A simple search for the method reveals ([this](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/PlayerInventory.html#getItemInHand())) documentation, stating:

> players can duel wield now use the methods for the specific hand instead

which referes to the `@see` references: 
[getItemInMainHand()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/PlayerInventory.html#getItemInMainHand()) and [getItemInOffHand()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/inventory/PlayerInventory.html#getItemInOffHand()).

Comment: So I have that documentation already and tried using getItemInMainHand() in my research but is not recognised as a usable method.

Comment: Looking at it I do not have a lot of the methods.

Comment: Maybe you also do not use 'Player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand()'

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
player.getInventory().getItemInMainHand()
```

Instead of:

```
player.getItemInHand()
```

Hope this helps! :D